# Trigger second ajax function based on the input from the first one

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Im trying to use a textbox value which was retrieved by first ajax function as data for the send Ajax function but the second Ajax function  does not do anything ( doesn't even show error in console and no object is being created  )

Here is my code of two functions ( please note that first Ajax function works perfectly )

```
$(document).on('change', '#hotelsid', function() { 
        var htid = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: "{{ route('hotel.tour') }}",
      data:{
       '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'selectedid': htid
       },
        success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $("#hotelid").val(data.hotelid);
           $("#rate").val(data.room);

      error: function(){
        console.log("Error Occurred");
      }
     });
   });  
$('#hotelid').trigger('change', function() {
      var hotid = $('#hotelid').val();
       console.log(hotid);
         $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url: "{{ route('hotel.rate') }}",
         data:{     
               '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
               'hotelid': hotid 
               //  'date': date1,            
               }, 
             success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#avail").val(data.rooms);
               },
            error: function(){
           console.log("Error Occurred");
                 }
     });
   });
```

Laravel controller function for the second

```
 public function getRates( $hotelid)
    {
     $rates=hotelroom::where('hotel_id',$hotelid)
                       ->first();    
      return response()->json($rates);

     }
```

Comment: what's wrong with consolidating this into a single function in your controller? look up the hotel id, then use that to query your rates and return both as part of the same json response?

Comment: You've added what seems to be an event handler in the second argument for `trigger()`, which is not the correct way to do this. Create the event handler separately, then `trigger` it later on. Also, as @maximus1127 states, it would make far more sense, and also be more scalable for your server, to merge these two AJAX requests in to one.

Comment: rates are  im saving date wise so there are multiple fields with same hotel id  in hotel room table

Comment: anything you're doing with ajax, you can do with eloquent in the controller. if you're just passing the returned hotel id to the second ajax function, whatever logic you have in that ajax function, just do that same logic in the controller.

Comment: @ maximus1127 Cannot do that because i have to show rates and availability in the form it self dynamically  ( this is a booking form )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second AJAX is suppose to trigger when the value of `hotelid` is changed, you should be doing.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#hotelsid', function() { 
  var htid = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "{{ route('hotel.tour') }}",
    data:{
      '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
      'selectedid': htid
    }, success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $("#hotelid").val(data.hotelid);
      $("#rate").val(data.room);
      onHotelIdUpdate(data.hotelid);
    }, error: function(){
      console.log("Error Occurred");
    }
  });
});
 
$(document).on('change', '#hotelid', function() {
  var hotid = $('#hotelid').val();
  onHotelIdUpdate(hotid);
});

function onHotelIdUpdate(val) {
  console.log('onHotelIdUpdate() called with the val: ', val);
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "{{ route('hotel.rate') }}",
    data:{     
      '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
      'hotelid': val 
       //  'date': date1,            
    }, success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $("#avail").val(data.rooms);
    }, error: function(){
      console.log("Error Occurred");
    }
  });
}
```

to assign an event listener to the `hotelid` which will be triggered once the value changes.

Comment: hi Mahan ,  i did on change too but it doesn't run either

Comment: Hmm, is `hotelid` dynamically generated onto the page after load? Or is it there from the beginning.

Comment: dynamically loaded in to the page

Comment: Alright then try this `$(document).on('change', '#hotelid', function() {`

Comment: I tried it but still no change , even the request object it self doesn't get created

Comment: Thank you so much Mahan , finally got it working after changing the request method from post to get

Comment: @Priceless Glad you got it figured it out. If this answer solved your issue can you please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the second one, on `#hotelid` to run after the dom has changed, try using the document syntax:

```
$(document).on('change', '#hotelid', function() {  }
```

This will capture the action after the change has been made - likely why nothing is happening on the previous method.